# DevExpress Winforms XtraGrid and SQLite bound database, best way to insert rows?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sqlite, devexpress

I have successfully bound a SQLite database table to a DevExpress XtraGrid control, and can see the few test rows I have, and can also edit the values, and commit the changes back to the database with an Update command upon closing.

My question is what would be the best way for me to insert rows to the table?  I have implemented and successfully used some example code for inserting rows into a SQLite table, however I am uncertain if the DevExpress XtraGrid has some type of method to allow me to skip all of the example code I have, and simply use the same functionality that seems to be already built into the control.

So should I use example code that connects to the database, builds the query then runs it on the database, or is there a better way, using something already built into the DevExpress WinForms suite?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of datasource are you using? DataTable, Linq, EntityFramework etc?

Comment: you should show us your `example code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that the best way to interact with the data in the grid, or with any database for that matter, is to use DevExpress's eXpress Persistent Objects for .NET.  Great bit of technology.  It allowed me to specify the database and table I was interested in, and it created all of the plumbing to allow me to deal with rows in the table like normal C# objects with properties.

If you are struggling with trying to mix in SQL queries and the like into your application, I highly recommend you make your life much easier and use XPO.

Here is a link to the documentation describing XPO: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument1998

Answer (score 1):

You can use Embedded Navigator controls to insert rows !

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q235790